# Building an Email for Gmail and my <img> keep being set to hidden

Tags: html, css, email, gmail, inline

I'm making an email HTML document for my company

Everything is fine other than a set of images that are meant to appear.
On Office they appear just fine but on Gmail the are hidden and when i look at the HTML in inspector i see that the style="display: none !important; visibility: hidden !important; opacity: 0 !important; background-position: 300px 32px;" has been added to the image.

Does anybody know why this is and how i can stop it.

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
      <tr>
        <td width="100%">
            <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border: 1px solid #45b75c;">
               <tr style="border: 1px solid #45b75c">
                  <td align="center" width="155" height="155" style="background-color: #f3f1f1;">
                     <img src="https://www.soccerhubb.com/assets/img/emails/world-cup/advert1.png" width="115" height="115" alt="Advertise to your target audience" line-height="" style="display: block;"/>
                  </td>
                  <td align="center">
                     <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 24px; color: #45b75c;">
                         Advertise to your target audience<br />
                         with intelligent analytics
                     </p>
                   </td>
               </tr>
            </table>
         </td>
     </tr>
<table>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gmail hides external e-mail images, even after user allows them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688965/gmail-hides-external-e-mail-images-even-after-user-allows-them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind i found out the issue.

As my image was called "advert1" spam filters caught it and assumed other content in the same table was also spam

note to self: don't use "advert" in alt tags or image names

Answer (score 0):

Use style tag and apply style with display:block !important 
In css !important keyword use for overwrite all style