# Gmail is removing src attribute for some images in my HTML email template

Tags: html, email, gmail

My HTML email template has a few images. All images are saved and served from the same Google Cloud Platform Storage Bucket and all images are set to be publicly available.

When the email is delivered, Gmail only loads half the images. In the other half, it removes the `src` attribute altogether! The same template works fine when I open it in Chrome and the same emails works great on Outlook.com as well. See the example of what the `<img>` tag looks like in Gmail below:

```
<img alt="image" style="display:block" width="191">
```

The HTML block for that specific image looks like this:

```
<td align="center">
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
     <img src="http://storage.googleapis.com/tripcloud-email-assets/campaigns/1-holidays-2016/banner-content-1.png" alt="image" border="0" height="67" width="199">
    </a>
</td>
```

The only other thread I found about this subject was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688965/gmail-hides-external-e-mail-images-even-after-user-allows-them) but I did not have a similar error and so, it was unrelated. Can someone please tell me why this might be happening?

Comment: Are you sure you haven't set up some sort of adblock or similar? Tried the email on a client/browser with no addons enabled?

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie Yes, I am sure. I don't have any ad-block enabled. I also checked the same email in the Inbox app by Gmail. Same results.

Comment: Maybe it has to do with image-size? I'm just spitballing here, I dunno, I'm just wondering. Have you tried changing the .png-file to something else? .jpg, .gif? Also, tried to change size, if possible?

Comment: I can't change it to a different format because the images have some transparency. I even set the height manually in all images. Didn't work. Heck, in some images, I didn't even specify the height and it worked. Strangely, I once renamed `/logo.png` in my Storage Bucket to `/SomeImage.png`. Gmail showed a "could not find image" icon. When I renamed it back and opened the email again, it worked! Sent the email again, stop working again.

Answer (score -8):

I can suggest you two options-

1. Don't use imagenames like `googleads` or `googleadspreview`. Just avoid 'ads words'.
2. If it removes `src` attribute, you can add it with jQuery.

Comment: You cannot use jQuery for an e-mail content.